# Picking up the first word in cell?

Tags: string, excel, startswith

I have a list of names where first name/names are in one column and last names in another. I have other smaller collection of names which I should find from the previous list. In this list I have only the first name and the last name of each person.

The problem is that I don't know how to compare the values since in other list I have one or more first names for a person and in another I have always just one first name for the person.

In excel I have used the next function:

```
LEFT(F3;FIND(" ";F3)-1)
```

**The problem is that there is also possibility that the cell consists of only one name, so " " can't be found and error occurs.**

How could I compare these two list properly?

And for more information, I should find and count the right persons found in first given list.

Comment: im not 100% sure of your problem but to get around some values having two first names and others not you can use if(iserror(LEFT(F3;FIND(" ";F3)-1)),F3,LEFT(F3;FIND(" ";F3)-1))           basically saying if your original formula has an error just put the first name

Comment: Thanks, got it working that way (IfError). This way I just need to create again a new list of names which makes the excel sheet messy. But it's acceptable. Thanks.

Comment: @99moorem, can you add this as an answer (which IngaB will hopefully accept).  Helps those of us looking for unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

im not 100% sure of your problem but to get around some values having two first names and others not you can use

```
if(iserror(LEFT(F3,FIND(" ",F3)-1)),F3,LEFT(F3,FIND(" ",F3)-1))
```

basically saying if your original formula has an error just put the first name

Answer (score 0):

If you append a space to the value, then there will always be at least one space in the right place.

```
=LEFT(F3; FIND(" "; F3&" ")-1)
```

As was pointed out in your question's comments, you can also pass back the origial value if an error occurs looking for a space but the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) may be more succinct.

```
=IFERROR(LEFT(F3; FIND(" "; F3)-1); F3)
```